# use a while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on some homework for a class and the assignment is in codingbat.com.  The problem is as follows:

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count.

So far, I have this:

```
def sum13(nums):  
    sum = 0  
    i = 0  
    while i in range(len(nums)):  
        if i == 13:  
            i += 2  
        else:  
            i += 1  
    return sum
```

Also, I had this code which works better:

```
def sum13(nums):
   sum = 0
   for i in range(len(nums)):
   if nums[i] != 13:
     sum += nums[i]
   return sum
```

I know I am supposed to use a while loop, but I just don't get this.

Comment: Can you specify better the *"numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count"*. Does it mean that the number 14 does not count?

Comment: Sure.  If the function is looking at a list of numbers [2, 5, 7, 13, 15, 19], the objective is to sum every number excluding (in this example) 13 and 15, it would still add 19 to the sum of the list.

Comment: The `range()` should not be used in the `while` loop.  The `range()` produces a sequence of numbers.  The `while` expects a boolean predicate.  The `while` as shown here will not pass a single loop, because the first value produced by the `range` is zero.  This is interpreted as the False value.  Also, the `return` is indented incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're almost there; you just need to actually add the value of `nums[i]` to `sum` in the appropriate place. Also reconsider the indentation of your `return sum` line.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ant P, I still don't have it figured yet, but I just wanted to say that after I posted, I started editing my post and it looks like I changed it after you answered, so due to that, I do not think the answer you gave is accurate for my incorrect solution.

Comment: Sorry, you're also checking whether the index (`i`) is 13, not the element at that index (`nums[i]`).

Answer (score 0):

It is more usual to use the `for` loops without using the `range()`.  That kind of loop (in Python) is usually used for looping through the element values, not through the index values.  When you need the index, use the `enumerate()` function to get both the index and the element value, like this (but you do not need it in the case):

```
...
for i, e in enumerate(nums):
    do something with index and/or the element
...
```

The problem is not related to index values.  This way, the `for` / `while` solutions differ only in accessing the elements of the array.  You need to use indexing with the `while` but you do not need indexing with the `for`.

The problem with your `while` approach also is that you cannot simply skip the index after the value 13 because the next element can also contain 13.  You need to store the value of the previous element and to use it for decision whether the current value should be added to the `sum` or not.  It will be the same in both `for` and `while` solutions. Something like this:

```
last = 0  # init; whatever value different from 13
sum = 0
the chosen kind of loop:
    e ... # current element from nums
    if e != 13 bool_operator_here last != 13:  # think about what boolean operator is
        add the element to the sum
    remember e as the last element for the next loop
sum contains the result
```

[Edited later] OK, you gave up.  Here is the code that solves the problem:

```
def sumNot13for(nums):
    last = 0  # init; whatever value different from 13
    sum = 0
    for e in nums:
        if e != 13 and last != 13:
            sum += e        # add the element to the sum
        last = e            # remember e as the last element for the next loop
    return sum


def sumNot13while(nums):
    last = 0  # init; whatever value different from 13
    sum = 0
    i = 0     # lists/arrays use zero-based indexing
    while i < len(nums):
        e = nums[i]         # get the current element
        if e != 13 and last != 13:
            sum += e        # add the element to the sum
        last = e            # remember e as the last element for the next loop
        i += 1              # the index must be incremented for the next loop
    return sum


if __name__ == '__main__':
   print(sumNot13for([2, 5, 7, 13, 15, 19]))
   print(sumNot13while([2, 5, 7, 13, 15, 19]))

   print(sumNot13for([2, 5, 7, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 15, 19]))
   print(sumNot13while([2, 5, 7, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 15, 19]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips pepr, I switched the tags to add homework.  First time posting here, so I appreciate help with proper etiquette.

Comment: I have modified the answer to reflect the clarification of the task.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand what you are saying to do, I just still do not get it.  Don't worry though, I am not continuing with programming classes after this one, and the class is almost over, less then a week to go!  I am so happy to almost be done with this.  :)

Comment: Well, you have a free will to decide :)

Comment: Thanks again pepr, it makes a little more sense now that I see the solution compared to what I had for the solution. Sorry to have let you (and myself) down by giving up.  ><  I really hate to disappoint. Again, thanks for the stackoverflow etiquette tips.

Comment: Everything has its own *right time*.  The fall can happen to anyone.  The bad thing would be to give up completely.  One case is not a probelm.  You will find you way.  The programming is not the most important thing on the World.  If any step is too big, you can always try more of the smaller steps.

Comment: Yeah, I am working on my IT degree.  Programming is just required to get us an introduction to that.  I know my limitations, and I am less interested in the programming aspect than other aspects of the degree.  I know my limitations.  Thankfully, the intro to programming is the only programming class I need.  I have done pretty well for the rest of the class, just got hung up on this one.  lol

Comment: You need to train your imagination.  Programming is nothing less than simulation of reality.  You have no limitations.  Possibly, you are not that lucky to recognize that in a short time.  Draw pictures of the problems on the paper.  Do the same as children do -- play the things in your head.  Do not be afraid of programming.  It is quite simple.  You only try to find the reason why it is above your limits. ;)